# Individual data property as range?

Tags: owl

Part of my master's thesis is to write a semantic resource broker. 
I prepare some simple ontology to describe cloud IaaS resources.
The user defines his requirements as a equivalent class.
Everything work fine when I cam define resource as individual with defined values ( reasoner can find all individual that match description) but sometimes I need to express some values as range ( for example disk size is between 512 MB and 2048 MB in my case).
I was thinking about some solutions but I'n not sure with is best:

- change resource offers from individuals to class descriptions and check   if intersection of resource offer and resource request is satisfiable
- add more special properties like ( max_size and min_size) and modify restrictions find proper individuals

maybe there is any other solution ?

Comment: OWL 2 Facet restriction ([1](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-quick-reference/#Facets), [2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Maps)) is what you want but works only for the built-in datatypes of OWL 2, e.g. `xsd:integer`

Comment: It's work fine for classes but can I achieve something similar for individuals ?

Comment: I don't understand. What means for individuals? The only statements about individuals are class assertions and property assertions.